# Firemonkey - updating visual components

Tags: delphi, user-interface, updates, firemonkey

We are working with Firemonkey since version 1, and still find difficulties updating components that are currently visible on the screen.  There are many 'ways' to request a repaint in Firemonkey, perhaps too many:

- Applying a style (ApplyStyle event) - mostly when it becomes visible on screen
- Requesting ".repaint" - some components have this
- Requesting ".realign" - sometime works, current versions of FMX seem to drop / hide it
- Requesting ".invalidate" - some components, mostly forms, have this
- Requesting ".invalidateRect" - most components have this
- Calling the ApplyStyle event manually - not guaranteed to work and design-wise is incorrect...

Given the lacking documentation for the platform, is there a "well defined" way to change the visual appearance (internal values of a style) when a component is already displayed?  I.e. a listboxItem that is already present and visible on screen, a TGrid cell, and so on.  Would appreciate your thoughts...

Comment: Thanks Peter - FMX is Delphi and also C++ :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a single unified 'correct way' to refresh the visual of components in Firemonkey.

However, as a recommendation from personal experience, I'd take the `.repaint` route - this method is at the `TControl` level, and so it precedes primitives and styled controls (which are generally made up of primitives) and so applies to all visual controls. It also doesn't require parameters, so it's a good all-round solution.

I have noted that Firemonkey has always had an issue correctly repainting controls of it's own accord. Often I'm left with a 'shadow' of the previous visual of a control/primitive, and must call `.repaint` manually to update it. This got noticeably worse with FM2 and FM3 (presumably due to optimizations made for mobile platforms), and so doing a manual `.repaint` -- especially where effects such as `TGlow` and moving or rotating controls/primitives are concerned, has become a standard practice for me.

Comment: .repaint is not in the scope of, for example, TForm (fmx);